# Jest silently ignores errors

Tags: jasmine, jestjs

Given the following test.js

```
var someCriticalFunction = function() {
    throw 'up';
};

describe('test 1', () => {
    it('is true', () => {
        expect(true).toBe(true);
    })
});

describe('test 2', () => {
    it('is ignored?', () => {
        someCriticalFunction();
        expect(true).toBe(false);
    })
});
```

Running Jest will output

```
Using Jest CLI v0.9.2, jasmine2
 PASS  __tests__/test.js (0.037s)
1 test passed (1 total in 1 test suite, run time 0.795s)
```

Which pretty much gives you the impression everything is great. So how do I prevent shooting my own foot while *writing* tests? I just spent an hour writing tests and now I wonder how many of them actually run? Because I will certainly not count all of them and compare with the number in the report.

Is there a way to make Jest fail as loud as possible when an error is thrown as part of the test suite, not the tests itself (like preparation code)? Putting it inside `beforeEach` doesn't change anything.

Comment: What if you put the `is ignored?` it into the first `describe` block - does it change anything? Thanks

Comment: It will run the tests until the point where the exception is thrown. So moving the test into the first block will make it run. `it` blocks after the failing one are also executed.

Comment: Haven't looked _very_ closely, but it seems to be related to [this](http://thurloat.com/2012/07/06/jasmine-swallowing-async-exceptions).

Comment: thanks @robertklep, what I describe was actually a bug. See my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is fixed in 0.9.3 jest-cli https://github.com/facebook/jest/pull/812

Which for some reason is unpublished again (I had it installed minutes ago). So anyway, throwing strings is now caught. You should never throw strings anyway and thanks to my test suite I found one of the last places I actually still threw strings...